# Why major social networks collect age but do not display it

Tags: social-media

I have noticed this on various social networks that during registration user is asked to specify age, however created user profile does not display the age.

Users on social networks that provide the bio text field usually put their age into the bio section anyway.

Is it illegal to display age of users who are below 18?

This is the only explanation I can think of, since dating websites and dating social networks that are for adults only, always display the age alongside the users profile.

Answer (score 1):

Many jurisdictions require parental consent to allow minors to sign up for social media. In the US the age is, I think, 13. They ask to ensure you are above that age.

Comment: Is there a law related reason many social networks do not display the age of the user in their user profile?